# Testing the Hypothesis of Differences in Expected and Observed Frequencies in a Population

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, multiple-regression

I have a set of data where I want to test the hypothesis that the player pool (a specific sample) overbluffs or underbluffs. I am assuming that if the player pool overbluffs or underbluffs, they do it for all sizings. I have a separate sample for all sizings. For example, the theoretical bluffing frequency for a half pot bet is 25%, however in my data, the player pool bluffed 114 times out of 323 samples. For a full pot, the theoretical bluffing frequency is 33%, but the player pool bluffed 33 times out of 100 samples. For a 150% bet, the theoretical bluffing frequency is 37.5%, but the player pool bluffed 4 times out of 20 samples.

I want to test this hypothesis using Python with a significance level of 0.05. I am looking for a method that gives a p-value for the aggregate of all samples. However, I do not want to use a binomial test for this. Can anyone suggest an appropriate statistical test or method to approach this problem?

I tried Chi-Squared test, but I am not sure whether it's suitable to use this scenario.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import chi2_contingency

observed_frequencies = np.array([114, 33, 4])
expected_frequencies = np.array([323*0.25, 100*0.33, 20*0.375])
chi2, p_value, _, _ = chi2_contingency([observed_frequencies, expected_frequencies])

print(p_value) # 0.17090289419933605
```

Comment: If you know the population bluffing rate, then there is nothing to hypothesize: if the sample comes from the population, then under the say an iid assumtion sample fraction of bluffing will be close to the the population fraction.

Comment: Can people who are part of the "half pot bet" group be also a part of the "full pot bet" group, or of the "150% bet" group? Also, why don't you want to use a binomial test? If this is a homework or self-learning question, you should mention that (you can add a "self-study" tag to your post for this purpose).

Comment: @J-J-J This is not a homework question, since I am a professional poker player. Nope this samples are different. Also I deleted 'using python' from the title.

Comment: If you're interested in testing the hypothesis that the whole population overbluffs or underbluffs, no matter their group ("half pot", "full pot", etc.), is there a reason not to collapse all the groups? You'll have observed values of 151 people bluffing and 292 not bluffing, to test against expected values of (121.25, 321.75). You could use a binomial test for that, but this is not clear why you don't want to (hence my initial guess that it might be a homework question!).

Comment: @J-J-J I can't group them into one since the theoretical frequency is different for all three groups

Comment: `sum([323*0.25, 100*0.33, 20*0.375])` = 121.5, here you have your overall expected frequency of people bluffing no matter their group.

Comment: Welcome to CV.  Note that you are using "population" in a confusing way; you seem to mean "sample".  The population would, presumably, be everyone who plays poker, at least under the conditions that your sample is playing.   And I have a question: Do you only have data for specific pot sizes?  (50, full, 150) or do you have it for all sorts of pot sizes?

Comment: @PeterFlom Sorry for obscure question: I fixed that. I've data for all sorts of pot sizes, but for simplicity I provided data only for 3 (50, full, 150).

Comment: On the information given a chi-squared test looks possible if you generate the expected theoretical frequencies and compare them with the observed but it is not absolutely clear to me what you are trying to do (and my knowledge of poker is very limited).